# Why do some applications open as separate buttons in the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

When I open an application button pinned to my taskbar, normally the app just opens, and an underline appears under its button. Yet when I open certain applications, they open under a duplicate button on the taskbar.

This is an example:

[image]

As you can see, I have Chrome, Slack, Explorer, and Foxxit Reader open, highlighted in green, all with just single, underlined buttons, but with Visual Studio, highlighted in red, the pinned button is not active and there is a duplicate button a little to the right.

Why do some apps do this and others not?

Answer (score 2):

About this issue, it's generally because that you could have pinned the shortcut of the file instead of the actual program. Find actual program, then right click it and select Pin to taskbar.

The solution is to find and remove the extra shortcut. The most straightforward way to do this is simply to right click and “Unpin” all the icons for the program in question, launch the program via the Start Menu, and then right click the running program on the taskbar to re-pin it.

Sometimes we’ve run into situations where this doesn’t resolve the problem. There’s usually a hidden shortcut that is being referenced by the running program.

In this case, the solution is to “Show Hidden Files” in Windows Explorer, and navigate to the system path for taskbar shortcuts. This path is : %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar – there you can attempt deleting the shortcut manually, and re-adding it once again.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the programs are just created that way, as it is the same on my computer. I don't think there is a particular reason for this, but it is interesting.

If it is an issue, I'm sure there's some work-arounds that can get it working.